# How to post back page while calling jquery colorbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, postback, colorbox

I am calling jquery color box in one of my applications. I can open it, but i want my page to postback first, while opening the color box simultaneously. I have tried below code.

aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenColorBox() {
            $.colorbox({
                opacity: 0.1,
                width: '350px',
                height: '350px',
                iframe: true,
                href: '/MMP/MMPhome.aspx',
                onLoad: function () {

                    $('#cboxClose').remove();
                },
                onClosed: function () {

                }
            });
        }

    </script>

<asp:Button ID="Call" runat="server" Text="Save this Search Criteria" 
                    OnClientClick="OpenColorBox(); return false;" onclick="Call_Click" />
```

It is opening popup, but i want to post back my page first.
If anyone knows how, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the postback to occur, THEN open your ColorBox, you can do the following:

ASCX:

```
<asp:Button ID="Call" runat="server" Text="Save this Search Criteria" 
                    onclick="Call_Click" />
```

Codebehind:

```
private void Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenColorBoxAfterClick", "OpenColorBox();", true);
   //Handle the rest of your code
}
```

If you need your postback to occur while opening your ColorBox, you will need to use Ajax. An UpdatePanel that contains the button would do the trick:

ASCX:

Codebeind:

```
private void Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Handle click as normal
}
```

If you need to use the UpdatePanel, but still call the javascript after the updatepanel returns:

ASCX:

```
<asp:Button ID="Call" runat="server" Text="Save this Search Criteria" 
                    onclick="Call_Click" />
```

CodeBehind

```
private void Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "OpenColorBoxAfterClick", "OpenColorBox();", true);
   //Handle click as normal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to call the button click event because colorbox renders the div which is shown to the user outside the form on the page. To over come this problem you have to a small change in the plugin.

Look for the appendHTML() function in the colorbox plugin and replace the below lines:

```
if (!$box && document.body)
```

with:

```
if (!$box && document.forms[0])
```

In the last line of the method, replace:

```
$(document.body).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
```

with

```
$(document.forms[0]).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
```

This solves the problem as now you'll have the colorbox rendered div inside the form tag!!